# How do I merge 5 identical MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I want to merge 5 identical-schema (okay, they are not exactly identical but I can edit the field names to make them identical) MySQL databases into one database. Is there any easy way?

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `name` VARCHAR (50) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `surname` VARCHAR (50) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `telephone` VARCHAR (50) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_turkish_ci PACK_KEYS = 0 ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Do they have indentical data? Or just identical schema?

Comment: @Asaph, they have identical schema.

Comment: Do they all live on the same MySQL server?  If so, a `UNION ALL` query for each table will do the job easily (unless you have lots of tables)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, they are not on the same MySQL server but I can port them all to one MySQL server.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I forget to mention that I want to merge not the whole database but only specific table (such as only the users tables)

Comment: @ilhan If you only need to merge one or a few tables and can get them into the same server, then you just need `CREATE TABLE combined SELECT ... FROM db1.t UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM db2.t... UNION ALL SELECT .. FROM db3.t...`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, do I need to remove the keys?

Comment: @ilhan If they collide, then yes. The `combined` table could be defined without a PK, however, then you won't get collisions. But you'll have to figure out what to do with the duplicate keys. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: Are all 5 tables using MyISAM ??? If they are all MyISAM, are they to be physically merged into one table or do you want them kept separate ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, now I don't remember that whether they are MyISAM or not but I can convert them into MyISAM. I want to merge them into one physical table.

Comment: First, please show the table's structure. What I mean is this: If the table is called `mydb.mytable`, then run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable\G` and post it in the question ody.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, I have posted it now.

Comment: Is there duplicate data amongst the five tables? Do you allow duplicate phone numebrs? Do you allow multiple people to share the same phone number? Do you allow a person to have multiple phone numbers?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, may be but I don't mind, would be better to see the dublicates. As dublicate theyere might be ID, phone number, Social Security Number. But having dublicates won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are exactly the same with column names/types and are named

- user1
- user2
- user3
- user4
- user5

there are two approaches to handle this:

## APPROACH #1 : Load the data into one table

```
CREATE TABLE user LIKE user1;
INSERT INTO user (name,surname,telephone,...)
SELECT name,surname,telephone,... FROM user1;
INSERT INTO user (name,surname,telephone,...)
SELECT name,surname,telephone,... FROM user2;
INSERT INTO user (name,surname,telephone,...)
SELECT name,surname,telephone,... FROM user3;
INSERT INTO user (name,surname,telephone,...)
SELECT name,surname,telephone,... FROM user4;
INSERT INTO user (name,surname,telephone,...)
SELECT name,surname,telephone,... FROM user5;
```

If the id is auto_increment all rows get new ids.

## APPROACH #2 : [Use the MERGE Storage Engine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10119/get-column-from-too-many-tables-in-mysql/10150#10150)

```
CREATE TABLE user LIKE user1;
ALTER TABLE user
    ENGINE=Mrg_MyISAM
    UNION=(user1,user2,user3,user4,user5)
;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this.

You could attempt to alter your tables within the different databases to bring them to be in the most similar format.

Additionally, you could use statements such as

```
Create table as select
```

in order to further format the data.

Than you would have to do a MYSQL DUMP of all your databases.
Select only the create statements from the database schema you are interested in following, and add your insert statements (for the data) from all the different databases.

You may also have to perform text manipulation in Excel, or from with mysql in order to get the data in such a format that it is compatible and can be inserted in your final schema.

Comment: Actually, there is, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Any ETL tool, like Clover, would be well suited for your purpose. Just define your column mappings and you should be good to go. Leave a comment if you need further help.